# Issues reading csv with footer and arbitray number of blank lines at end

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have issues using the pandas package for reading a .csv file with a single footer and an arbitrary number (>= 0) of blank lines at the end of the file (blank lines come after the footer). For example this is my .csv file:

```
col_1, col_2
1, 30
2, 40
3, 50
(last row)
```

(I can not show what should be an arbitrary number of blank lines at the end, because the SO editor however doesn't parse them) (to avoid any confusion `(last row)` is the footer)

[image]

When I run:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, engine='python', skipfooter=1, skip_blank_lines=True)
        col_1   col_2
0           1    30.0
1           2    40.0
2           3    50.0
3  (last row)     NaN
```

I get the undesired row with index 3:

```
(last row)     NaN
```

An undesired spin-off are values in my first column all being string instead of int's and the values in the 2nd column are float's instead of int's.

I can fix it by truncating the last row and converting the columns to the right type, however it should be possible by giving the right parameters to the `skipfooter` argument or the `skip_blank_lines` argument. However whatever parameters I use, it fails. What is going wrong?

I use pandas version 0.20.3 and Python 2.7.12 on a Linux system.

Comment: I couldn't re-reproduce reported behaviour with same pandas and python 2.7.13. Please double check your source file - empty lines are not a reson for NaNs. At least, you should not put spaces after commas, because their being considered as part of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can create you own parser pretty easily like:

#### CSV Parser:

```
def read_my_csv(file_handle):
    # build csv reader
    reader = csv.reader(file_handle)

    # for each row, check for footer
    for row in reader:
        if row[0].strip() == '(last row)':
            break
        yield row
```

#### To Use:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open ("test.csv", 'rU') as f:
    generator = read_my_csv(f)
    columns = next(generator)
    df = pd.DataFrame(generator, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
  col_1  col_2
0     1     30
1     2     40
2     3     50
```

Comment: Yes I know. Thanks for that. However for this one I try to use as much library code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could reproduce you behaviour by putting special symbol `^A` in the last line.

If I print file to the console, there is nothing special:

```
$cat test.csv
col_1, col_2
1, 30
2, 40
3, 50



$
```

But looking at hexdump, you could see unusual `01` at 19th position:

```
$hexdump -C test.csv
00000000  63 6f 6c 5f 31 2c 20 63  6f 6c 5f 32 0a 31 2c 20  |col_1, col_2.1, |
00000010  33 30 0a 32 2c 20 34 30  0a 33 2c 20 35 30 0a 01  |30.2, 40.3, 50..|
00000020  0a 0a                                             |..|
00000022
$
```

When reading such file with pandas, I got exactly the same results you described.

The easier way to check you file is to view it with `less` command-line tool:

```
$less test.csv
col_1, col_2
1, 30
2, 40
3, 50
^A

$
```

The way to fix this situation depends on how this special char come to the file.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. However your test.csv doesn't seem to have have a proper footer.

Comment: Ok, it is much clearlier now - you have footer indicator and unknown number of empty lines after it. If we take look at Pandas [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/io/parsers.py#L2901-L2906) , we could find it first removing footer lines and *after* this checking for newlines. Hence I suggest you to go with @Stephen solution. It matches your case exactly.

Comment: Yes I was already expecting this. Not convinced this is desired behavior. I think removing blank lines has to be the package first priority. Maybe one of the pandas experts here can comment on this? Or maybe they fixed it in the latest release 0.21.0 which is however still a candidate release.